# C/C++ のメモリサイズが他の言語よりコンパクトになるのはなぜですか？

Tags: c++, c, プログラミング言語

C/C++ でプログラムを作っていると、他の言語に比べてコンパイルされたプログラムのメモリサイズがコンパクトになることがよくあります。

コンパイラなどの仕様はあまり知らないのですが、Java で同じコードを書いたときより、数十パーセントほどコンパクトなメモリ管理ができることもたまにあるのです。

なぜC/C++ では他の言語よりもコンパクトなメモリ管理ができるのでしょう？ 他の言語では暗黙的にコードに記述されていない処理をプログラムに付加しているのでしょうか？

Comment: 「コンパクト」の単位を示してください。実行ファイルサイズでしょうか？ 実行時の使用メモリでしょうか？ ソースコードサイズではなさそうですね。

Comment: 多種多様な言語があるので、比較対象は明確にした方がよさそうです。 / 見方によっては比較対象側の方がCやC++よりも肥大化しがち、とも考えられます。

Comment: コンパクトになったのは、実行ファイルそのものでした。説明が曖昧でした。

Comment: 比較相手が珍しい記事。[Executable Size: Rust, Go, C, and C++](https://dev.to/aakatev/executable-size-rust-go-c-and-c-1bna) 割と一般的な例。p29-30 [Comparing Programming Languages in Google Code Jam](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/250672/250672.pdf) 類似でファイルサイズではなく使用メモリサイズとか。[Perl, Python, Ruby, PHP, C, C++, Lua, tcl, javascript and Java comparison](https://raid6.com.au/~onlyjob/posts/arena/)

Comment: コンパクトになったのは、実行ファイルではなく、明示的にメモリを確保するために小さくなるメモリサイズのことだと思います。実行ファイルではなかったようです。間違えました。

Comment: 回答を受けてから別の質問文に切り替えるのはやめてください。

Answer (score 2):

ちなみにC++言語とC#言語でHello, Worldを書いてみました。普通にC言語やC++言語の方が大きいです。コンパクトになる例が知りたいです。

C言語 10,752bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

C++言語 11,776bytes.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

C#言語 4,608bytes.

```
using System;
namespace CsHelloWorld {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: すみません、メモリサイズが小さくなるの間違いでたぶん間違いないと思います。Malloc などでメモリ管理をするため、メモリサイズが明示的にしか確保されないため、メモリサイズがコンパクトになるという事例について質問しているようでした。